# How to keep leading zeros when writing to CSV file in python

Tags: python, csv

I have some code that reads through a list of HTML files, takes some information from each of these, and then presents them in a CSV file.

Part of this is using the number from the file's name to display which hour that line of data is from (e.g. file name is Report_H1.html). However, in order to get these to display in the correct order, I have padded out each number with 0's to make them all 2 decimal places.

When writing these to the CSV file, the leading 0's are removed. How can I prevent this from happening?

Edited code down to just the part that is causing my issue:

```
import re
import csv
import os

BASE_DIRECTORY = "C:\\Users\\MHE36\\Documents"
fileList = []

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for f in filenames:
        if 'html' in str(f):
            e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
            boxName = os.path.dirname(e)
            box = os.path.basename(boxName)
            fileDict = {}
            fileList.append(fileDict)
            match = re.search(r'\d+', f)
            if match:
                fileDict['Hour'] = str(match.group(0).zfill(2))

with open('C:\\Users\\MHE36\\Documents\\test.csv', 'w') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, ['Hour'])
    w.writeheader()
    for fileDict in fileList:
        w.writerow(fileDict)

print(fileList)
print(fileDict)
```

and this is the output of the print commands:

```
[{'Hour': '01'}, {'Hour': '10'}, {'Hour': '11'}, {'Hour': '12'}, {'Hour': '13'}, {'Hour': '14'}, {'Hour': '15'}, {'Hour': '16'}, {'Hour': '02'}, {'Hour': '03'}, {'Hour': '04'}, {'Hour': '05'}, {'Hour': '06'}, {'Hour': '07'}, {'Hour': '08'}, {'Hour': '09'}, {'Hour': '01'}, {'Hour': '02'}, {'Hour': '03'}, {'Hour': '04'}, {'Hour': '05'}]
{'Hour': '05'}
```

In the above `print`s, I can see the leading zeros are being added as I want them. However, in the CSV file, I get the following:

```
Hour                
1
```

I want it as:

```
Hour                
01
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is in the raw CSV file? Is your spreadsheet software formatting the leading zero away?

Comment: Any chance of reducing that to a [mcve]? A minimal toy example that reproduces the error? Just an example of the data you are trying to write to the file and what you expect the file to look like?

Comment: I'm using Excel so I think it is the software formatting that is causing the issue, I'm just wondering if there is a way of using the python code to stop that happening? thanks

Comment: just add a single quote before the leading zero like this: '01

Comment: Cannot reproduce, the csv file has leading zeros that match the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with Python's csv module (as you would have found out reading the csv file directly in your code editor), but with Excel considering unquoted numerics as, well, numerics.

I don't use nor have Excel (linux user here) so I can't double-check, but passing `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` when creating the writer should fix the issue (this will add quote chars around all your numerics so excel should consider them as strings and leave them alone)

The doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer

NB : if you only want to have SOME fields quoted, you'll have to do so manually when building the `fileDict`.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in another answer and it worked for me:

`df['column']=df['column'].apply('="{}"'.format)`